# Goldbach-conjecture tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

It may seem silly but I have noticed that the goldbach-conjecture tag is spelled wrong: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golbachs-conjecture. Do we really need it by the way? Only 5 questions have the tag as of now.

Comment: Only one of those questions is still open. I would suggest either removing, or merging the tag with another (maybe just number theory?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goldbachs-conjecture)